# YouTube shows Doubled/Incorrect video length

Tags: youtube, video-conversion

Just before an hour i screen captured and encoded a video (using Microsoft Expression 4) and then cropped that video using Format Factory and later uploaded on YouTube (.mp4) format.

Original video length : 10 Mins 08 Secs
After cropping : 8 Mins 35 Secs
Before uploading to YouTube : 8 Mins 35 Secs
After uploading on YouTube : 17 Mins 11 Secs

Size of my video is getting almost double after uploading.. ha ha funny ;)

What's wrong in this? Have I made some mistake in converting/cropping my video or it's a YouTube problem?

I've uploaded some screen shots for a clear explanation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you try opening it in VLC,WMP, do they both report the shorter length? even try dragging it into Windows Movie Maker see if that one also shows the shorter length. And try cropping it in xilinx.

Comment: @BBlake a little diagnosis may show that this isn't really a youtube problem, or that the problem can be shown also in applications separate from youtube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

Expression Studio encoded my video in (.wmv) file format, so converting the video using Format Factory in (.mp4) is causing some problems, this length remains same if played on windows media player or VLC, but uploading on YouTube is doubling its length.

So if I encoded my video (.wmv) format and uploaded directly to YouTube, everything works fine, but converting it to (.mp4) and then uploading to YouTube is doubling the video length.

**Conclusion** : Problem is with Format Factory converting.

Comment: you can mark your own answer as correct

Comment: @soandos :) ...

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this same problem on youtube by going into edit video, enhance, trim. and then setting the trim the the full length of the video and saving. youtube shows that it is editing and then the correct duration was displayed

Comment: You might need to be converted to a comment, feel free to flag a mod and ask for this to be done until you earn enough rep to write comments... this is an easy and simple task too by the way.